# Show a grid of equally spaced images with layout() and display()

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, image-processing

I want to create a grid of 9 images with equal spacing between them. Until now I managed to get something to work with `par()` and `layout()`.

```
layout(matrix(1:9, widths=rep(lcm(4),9), heights=rep(lcm(3),9))

for (i in 1:9) {
    imNew <- readImage(img_ar[i])
    EBImage::display(imNew, method="raster")
}
```

gives me this

[image: no spcaing in between individual images]

while using par:

```
layout(matrix(1:9, widths=rep(lcm(4),9), heights=rep(lcm(3),9))

for (i in 1:9) {
    imNew <- readImage(img_ar[i])
    EBImage::display(imNew,method="raster")
}
```

gives me this:

[image: vertical spacing]

I also tried different options for `par()` like `oma`, `mai` and `mar` but these didn't change the spacing in between the individual images. What I like to have is an equal distance between the individual images like this:

[image: result]

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: You mention using `par()` in your second code chunk but didn't actually include the corresponding code setting it (the code is the same as in the first example, yet the result you show is different). For the sake of clarity and completeness, would you mind adding the missing bits? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your original idea to separate images by including additional empty rows and columns in your layout, as in the following example. Note, however, that in order to achieve equal horizontal and vertical spacing you will need to tweak the device dimensions.

```
library(EBImage)

# load sample image
img <- readImage(system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage"))

# downsample to reduce memory consumption and for faster processing
img <- resize(img, 192)

# build the layout matrix with additional separating cells
nx <- 4 # number of images in a row
ny <- 3 # number of images in a column

cols <- 2*nx-1
rows <- 2*ny-1
m <- matrix(0, cols, rows)
m[2*(1:nx)-1, 2*(1:ny)-1] <- 1:(nx*ny)
m <- t(m)

# relative spacing
pad <- .1

w <- rep(1, cols)
w[!(1:cols)%%2] <- pad
h <- rep(1, rows)
h[!(1:rows)%%2] <- pad * dim(img)[1L]/dim(img)[2L]

layout(m, widths = w, heights = h)

layout.show(nx*ny)

for (i in 1:(nx*ny)) {
  display(img, method="raster")
}
```

[image]

A better approach is to use `display()` on an image stack. Then individual frames can be displayed arranged in a grid by setting `all=TRUE`.

```
## construct sample image stack
img_stack <- combine(replicate(nx*ny, img, simplify=FALSE))

display(img_stack, method="raster", all=TRUE)
```

[image]

Unfortunately, until recently it was not possible to adjust the spacing between the frames. To facilitate this, I've added an argument to `display()` specifying the `spacing`. Currently this new feature is available in the development version of *EBImage*, which can be obtained either from GitHub `devtools::install_github("aoles/EBImage")`, or from the [Bioconductor devel branch](http://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/html/EBImage.html).

The spacing can be provided as a fraction of frame dimensions (positive numbers <1) or in pixels (numbers >=1). Additionally, you can have different horizontal and vertical separation by providing a vector, e.g. `spacing = (10, 20)` will separate the columns by 10px, and the rows by 20px.

```
display(img_stack, method="raster", all=TRUE, spacing=.1)
```

[image]

Furthermore, you can add a `margin` around the grid, and control its layout by `nx`. The background can be set through `bg` passed to `par()`.

Finally, a completely different way of drawing images in a grid is to construct one big composite image with `tile`. This approach might be useful, for example, when saving the result to a file. Note the additional border around the whole grid.

```
## tiled composite image
img_tiles <- tile(img_stack, nx=nx, lwd=20, fg.col="white", bg.col="white")    

display(img_tiles, method="raster")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `ggplot2` way with `marrangeGrob()` from `gridExtra`:

```
library(RCurl)
library(png)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

# read a few MNIST images
urls <- c('https://i.imgur.com/TEbkTqu.png', 'https://i.imgur.com/tnsjMFJ.png', 'https://i.imgur.com/VUZgJBs.png', 'https://i.imgur.com/FZ28d3w.png')
imgs <- list()
for (i in 1:length(urls)) {
  imgs[[i]] <- readPNG(getURLContent(urls[i]))
}

# plot grid and show images
plist <- list()
for (i in 1:length(imgs)) {
  plist[[i]] <- ggplot() +
    annotation_custom(rasterGrob(imgs[[i]], interpolate=TRUE), xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)  +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
    guides(x = "none", y = "none") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "none", panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
}
marrangeGrob(plist, nrow=2, ncol=2, respect=TRUE)
```

[image]

(Demonstrated here in the [shiny app](https://sandipan.shinyapps.io/MNIST_VIZ/?_ga=2.49444462.919779508.1628157044-1321811131.1628157044) too)